# Where can I find what type of loss metric a model uses?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

[image]

I am trying to figure out what loss functions are used in ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco but I can't seem to find where it is specified in the repo or online. This is my Tensorboard for my loss while training but it doesn't specify what the loss metric is.

Link to repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

I am following this tutorial: 
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#8-use-your-newly-trained-object-detection-classifier

I've tried looking through the config file and some parts of the code but didn't see what type of metric it uses.

Is there a location where I can find the loss metric used for each type of model architecture on the repo? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the loss functions used in the [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config#L110). The loss is comprised of two losses: `weighted_sigmoid` for classification, `weighted_smooth_l1` for localization, each with weight of 1. To see the code of these losses you can check the [loss functions here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/losses.py). Note the total loss has another component for regularization.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help. If it answered your question, please set the answer with V to let others with the same question know that this answer is correct/helpful.